# Wrap React-slick <li> slides inside <ul>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-slick

I want to wrap all of my `React-slick slides` which are `li` inside `ul`. I went through the documentation and found that `slide` prop can be used for changing the `container` element. It takes an wrapping element name as `string`. The default is `div`, I changed it to `ul` but still I'm getting div as container `div`.

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    let settings = {
      dots: true,
      infinite: true,
      speed: 500,
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      slide: "ul"
    };
    return (
      <Slider {...settings}>
        <li>
          <h3>1</h3>
        </li>
        <li>
          <h3>2</h3>
        </li>
        <li>
          <h3>3</h3>
        </li>
        <li>
          <h3>4</h3>
        </li>
        <li>
          <h3>5</h3>
        </li>
        <li>
          <h3>6</h3>
        </li>
      </Slider>
    );
  }
}
```

Codesandbox link https://codesandbox.io/s/0xjlvkp9jl